# boost::thread: notify when first thread in thread_group has finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have a `boost::thread_group`, which I have initialized using `thread_group`,

e.g. `thread_group tg1;`

and populated using `create_thread`.  While using `create_thread`, the threads start execution.

The various threads in my thread group can finish execution at different times.  I know one can use `tg1.join_all()` if the objective is to wait for **all** of the threads in the thread group to finish executing.

However, what I would ideally like to do is call this function, wait for the most recently finished thread, remove it from the group and use the thread results in an appropriate manner, and then call the function again (it will either wait if no other thread has finished execution or it will immediately return the next thread that has finished execution, just like a regular `join()` function) until the group is empty.

Is there any function in the boost libraries that can return the thread ID of the thread that has finished first?

Comment: A method thread_group::join_any()  would help. Unfortunately it does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a queue with a condition variable to wait on.  When any thread finishes, it would put its results (or a reference to them or to the thread itself) on this queue, and signal the condition.